# Problem with Cordova plugin file transfer on Android 8

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, phonegap

My problem occurs when I try to send a video to server in android 8 or 8.1.1 (on previous versions works fine)  I print vars post ($_POST) and vars files ($_FILES)  teh result is empty.

```
var options = new FileUploadOptions();
options.fileKey = "MyVido";
options.fileName = nameVideo;
options.mimeType = "video/mp4";
//options.mimeType = "multipart/form-data"; Don't works
//options.chunkedMode = false; Don't works
options.headers = {
    Connection: "close"
};
var params = {};
params.pass = mipass;
params.ideVideo = idevideo;

options.params = params;
var ft = new FileTransfer();
ft.upload(file, encodeURI(urlComprobarVideo), videoIsOk(), videoKO() ,options);
```

I also updated the version android targetSdkVersion to 26.

Before this update the videos were sent well on android 8.

Thanks for your help.